# Building material-ui with browserify

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, material-ui

I'm trying to build the material-ui (material-ui.com) javascript so that I can include it in my project and use the react components. I've been using browserify to bundle all the javascript into a single file, which I then include in my HTML file. So, in the material-ui/lib directory (which is where the JSX-transformed JS seems to live -- I'm very new to NPM bundles + browserify etc), I run

browserify index.js -o material-ui.js -r material-ui

I then include that material-ui.js file in my HTML.

But then when I try writing require('material-ui') in my javascript in the HTML page I get "Cannot find module 'material-ui'".

I don't really understand what browserify is meant to be doing, what the require function is doing, and how I'm meant to reference any of the material-ui react classes. Thanks!

Comment: It is better to replace last paragraph with the list of technologies you are familiar with. Will the paragraph be shorter? And what size of answer you'd expect?

Comment: I'm familiar with front-end JS, react and it's usage, command line tools, etc. It's really the node ecosystem (browserify/reactify etc) that I struggle with, as the documentation is pretty poor, and how to use them to build (in this instance) material-ui into something I can use on the front end with my react code.

Answer (score 1):

So I just managed to solve this. Browserify was creating a require() function but not the material-ui module because I was calling it from the wrong directory. Calling it from the npm's module root without specifying a starting .js point somehow made it actually work, allowing me to use require('material-ui') without any errors.